# swift realm List<T> not populating

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

I am using realm with ObjectMapper in swift. I am not able to populate the list. It is always nil. Here is my code:

```
import RealmSwift
import ObjectMapper

class Person: Object,GtMappable {
   dynamic var id = 0
   dynamic var name = ""
   dynamic var listOfEmployees = List<Employee>()


    required init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(_ map:Map) {
        super.init()
        mapping(map)
    }

    // Mappable
    internal func mapping(map: Map) {
        id    = map["id"]
        name  = map["name"]
        listOfEmployees <- map["result"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ObjectMapper's design (specifically, its reliance on `inout` parameters) makes it incompatible with Realm. See https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/issues/31 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The List type is a Realm type which ObjectMapper doesn't support out of the box.

Others have solved the problem by creating a CustomTransform. Here is a solution that should work for you:
https://gist.github.com/Jerrot/fe233a94c5427a4ec29b

You can also see more discussion on the issue here:
https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/issues/143

Answer (score 0):

I've created an operator which properly fixes this issue. Please, check https://gist.github.com/danilValeev/ef29630b61eed510ca135034c444a98a
With this operator you don't need any additional code or transforms.
`list <- map["name"]`

Answer (score 0):

You must apply a RealmListTransform to the lists in your mapping function:

```
      listOfEmployees <- (map["result"], RealmListTransform<Employee >())
```

In swift 3.0 your code may be simpler:

```
import RealmSwift
import ObjectMapper

class Person: Object,GtMappable {
   dynamic var id = 0
   dynamic var name = ""
   dynamic var listOfEmployees = List<Employee>()

   required convenience init?(map: Map) {
      self.init()
   }

   // Mappable
   internal func mapping(map: Map) {
      id    <- map["id"]
      name  <- map["name"]
      listOfEmployees <- (map["result"], RealmListTransform<Employee >())
   }
}
```

Comment: listOfEmployees will throw an error - `Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C`